# unable to locate element of drop down menu(written in boot strap)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, dropdown

I have used all sorts of locator to locate the web element of drop down but it is not working everytime I am getting this error:

> Unable to locate element

I am trying for the given url to login and select the calender here: https://classic.crmpro.com/

I have used following ways to locate after using implicit wait:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

1. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://classic.crmpro.com/system/index.cfm?action=calendar&sub=default']")).click();
2. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navmenu']/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
3. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Calendar']")).click();
4. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Calendar')]")).click();
5. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Calendar']")).click();
   Thread.sleep(1000);

Every time it is throwing an error like:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1) on port 12336
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Mar 31, 2019 3:45:38 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@title='Calendar']"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'YESHI', ip: '192.168.0.103', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a..., userDataDir: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\T...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50027}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.86, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 5e04eddb3f57b98161681cab972a5b2a
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@title='Calendar']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at YeshiProject.demo.main(demo.java:34)
```

Please let me know what can I do.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide the html of the entire navmenu. I am not able to access the page that you mentioned as it need the user credentials.

Comment: Do you have dummy set of credentials to be used by the contributors?

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem solved? If not, please do this.

The element that you meant is inside the `iframe`, so you have to switch first.

This is the `iframe` I mean : `By.name("mainpanel")`

After login you can do this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("mainpanel")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Calendar']")).click();
```

It will click the `calendar`, but if you just want move to element and make the dropdown appear, then do this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("mainpanel")));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Calendar']"))).perform();
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Sorry for the credentials, my suggest change your credentials and delete it from this site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and would delete the creds